# Spring Controller unable to return JSON

Tags: xml, json, spring, tomcat, web

I have a spring controller with multiple methods each of which return data in XML or JSON based on the headers. All the methods return the data successfully except one method which **has an issue in returning JSON data**. All I see is "500 Internal Server Error" in the logs

This is how my method looks like:

```
@RequestMapping (value="/test", method=RequestMethod.GET, headers ={"Accept=text/xml, application/json"})
public @ResponseBody MyObject getMyObject() throws FileNotFoundException, JAXBException {

    return getMyService().getMyObject();
}
```

Eclipse console doesn't show any error, **Tomcat logs only display the "500 Internal Server Error"** and if I debug then getMyService().getMyObject() has the correct data. So what is the cause for the 500 error? and why is it working fine for XML requests but not for JSON? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The issue was I didn't provide public getters for a couple of private variables in MyObject.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this problem is occuring when json serialization fails (see also here [Internal server error on Jackson @ResponseBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594834/internal-server-error-on-jackson-responsebody)). While it is still not entirely clear to me, why we do not receive the exception through Spring, this short answer turned out very practical to me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25011673/4340425 .

In short: By instantiating an object mapper by hand and trying to serialize the object you can get the exception that reveals the problem (often missing getter or attempting to serialize some non-primitive whith no appropriate mapper specified).